# Bazel in TensorFlow and C++

Tags: c++, tensorflow, bazel

I'm trying to build a project with Tensorflow in C++, have installed already TensorFlow from source with Bazel and now I'm following the Tensorflow C++ API. But to run the first mini-program of the documentation (C++ API Guide: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/cc/guide) takes about an hour. Is that normal?

Comment: Opinion based question are not welcome. Add your code and show current performance. For more details please check [How to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: I do not see this as an option based question. This is a valid question!
I experienced the same behavior. Consecutive compilation passes will, however, be faster. This might be the reason that most people scream for an official supported CMake way.

Comment: Including the steps you took would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What platform are you building on? What version of bazel? [Sandboxing](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#sandboxing) got much faster recently, but you can try disabling it.

Also note that incremental builds with bazel are faster (and correct :).